# Notation for vector in a subset of the real plane

Tags: notation, vectors

$x \in R^N$ denotes a $N$ element row vector where each value is a real number. What if values of the vector are between 0 and 1 (exclusive)? Is $x \in (0, 1)^N$ the correct notation?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I guess I can close the question... or if you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This notation is correct. Formally, an element of $A^B$ is a function $B\to A$. When we write something like $A^5$, you can interpret this as $A^B$ for some set $B$ with five elements (i.e. $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$). You can think of a function $\{1,2,3,4,5\}\to A$ as just an ordered list of five elements of $A$, hence $A^5$ consists of $5$-tuples $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)$. Hence this set-theoretic definition of $\Bbb R^5$ agrees with the interpretation as a Cartesian product.

But also note that $R^N$ makes sense for any sets $R$ and $N$. If $R$ is a field (like $\Bbb R$), then generally $R^N$ is understood to have the usual vector space structure. On the other hand, $(0,1)^3$ is not a vector space in any obvious way. (It still can be considered as a subset of $\Bbb R^3$ though.)